# API Call using a Promise or Async returning a variable with the data

Tags: node.js, api, promise

NB:I am new to Node.js

I would like to call a function in the current module and it perform the data pull with a promise or async function. Then be able to access the data in a variable. Once it is a variable out of the promise maybe I can store/use/investigate the data. Any help would be much appreciated.

I manged to get the code below to run but I am not really sure if it is correct?  Is there a cleaner/proper way to do this? Very confused.

I have tried to write a promise but I am going in circles.

```
const publicClient = new CoinbasePro.PublicClient();
const coinbasePro = require('coinbase-pro')

const p = new Promise((resolve, reject)  => {
    yourFunction()
      async function yourFunction() {
      try {
        const products = await publicClient.getProducts();
        resolve(products);
        //console.log('ArrayName', products);
        return products
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    }
  });

  p.then(result => console.log('Result', result))
  p.catch(err => console.log('Error', err.message));
```

1) I would like to be able to invoke this promise from the same module and get the data in a variable.

2) I would like to be able to invoke this promise from another module and get the data in a variable.

Comment: Tip: don't mix promises with async/await. Choose one and be consistent.

Comment: How do I write this as just async or a promise. I am struggling with this I am new to the syntax.

Comment: Assuming `publicClient.getProducts()` returns a promise you can: `publicClient.getProducts().then(console.log).catch(console.error)`

Comment: Or use async/await notation: `const res = await publicClient.getProducts(); console.log(res);` and etc

Comment: disagree w/ @alfasin,  Async/Await is blocking whereas if you have function that can run unblocked, you should do so. Use case is a controller that runs many asynchronous operations without dependencies.

Now, I do agree that you are mixing the two in a poor fashion. Without seeing the code for `getProducts()`, it really hard to tell the **proper** way handle.

Comment: @LostJon Promise().then() is also blocking ;)

Comment: Thanks, publicClient.getProducts().then(console.log).catch(console.error) writes to the console. How do I get this data into a variable? Please see link for api. https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-pro-node

Comment: `publicClient.getProducts().then(products => { console.log(products) })` or, if you like async/await `let products = await publicClient.getProducts()`

Comment: Really appreciate the help. The first option worked. I was unable to get the async/await to work, it returned 'SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function'.

Comment: "*Once it is a variable out of the promise*" - not gonna happen. You cannot read the asynchronous result value out of the future. Instead, you need to defer your computation using the value into the future, by placing it inside a `then` callback or after an `await` keyword.

Comment: @Alastair in your example you're not doing anything with `products` but from your comments it sounds like you _do_ want to do something with it. Please explain better what you want to achieve - it will help _you_ get better help ;)